# Differences of NSDocument and UIDocument in iCloud development for ios

Tags: ios, icloud, nsdocument, uidocument

Can some one explain me what are differences of UIDocument class and NSDocument class when it comes to developing iCloud for an ios app?
which one is better for file-based application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIDocument is on iOS NSDocument is on Mac OS

Comment: Are you sure that we can't use NSDocument on IOS?

Comment: er, yes. look in the documentation. `The NSDocument abstract class defines the interface for OS X documents.`